# How do I resolve hostnames on the local network in Linux Mint?

Tags: networking, hostname, linux-mint

Nothing on Google, other questions on the stack websites or anywhere else seems to answer my question.

Let's pretend that my Windows laptop is using the device name `mylaptop`.  Other Windows' devices connected to the same network can contact `mylaptop` by the host name alone.  Linux Mint can only contact `mylaptop` by using its dynamic IP address (192.168.0.8) instead.

Is it possible for Linux Mint 17 to automatically resolve host/device names over the network?  If so, how?

I know Windows does this in an ugly manner and I ain't bothered if I can get my Linux box to achieve the same thing in a similar way.

Comment: I'd try the accepted answer from this [Ask Ubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20313/name-resolution-on-home-lan).

Comment: Firstly, libnss-mdns is already installed, secondly, they want their Ubuntu system to be discovered by other devices...  That doesn't resolve hostnames to other devices connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to resolve windows hosts from your linux machine, you might just need to install the `samba` package so you get `winbind`.  Also, install the `libnss-winbind` package. Then edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from this:

`hosts:      files dns`

to this:

`hosts:      files dns wins`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, linux doesn't do it by default, so you'd have to set it up manually on `/etc/hosts` or using a `DDNS server` + a `DHCP server`.